# Using $@ at prerequisite in Makefile

Tags: makefile

All

I just want to using $@ at prerequisite in a Makefile like this

```
test.v: $(@:%.v=%.tv)
    echo $< $@
```

It suppose output

```
test.tv test.v
```

but it only output

```
test.v
```

Anything I miss?

Comment: You are, in fact, using `$@`. What you are not printing is `$<`. I'm not sure why it wouldn't print, but you could try other automatic variable for the dependencies, like `$^` or `$|`

Comment: You are misusing the automatic variable `$@` in a prerequisite context. This only works when you escape it with `$$` and put the rule(s) under a `.SECONDEXPANSION:` pseudotarget. See more [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reference target variable from dependency list you first need to enable [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion), then you can delay evaluation of targets and functions with `$$` instead of `$`, i.e.:

```
$ cat Makefile
.SECONDEXPANSION:

test.v: $$(patsubst %.v,%.tv,$$@)
        echo $@ $<

test.tv:

$ make
echo test.v test.tv
test.v test.tv
```

Note that you cannot use shortened notation of `$$(@:%.v=%.tv)` due to some parser limitations around static pattern rules.

Anyway, what you are trying to do is doable with simple [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
$ cat Makefile2
%.v: %.tv
        echo $@ $<

%.tv: ;

$ make -f Makefile2 test.v
echo test.v test.tv
test.v test.tv
```

This would make a generic rule for creating `.v` files out of `.tv` files, but will require explicit call of a target (as a pattern rule does not create a specific file to build on its own).

If you wish to limit allowed file naming to follow the rule, you may go with a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$ cat Makefile3
test.v: %.v: %.tv
        echo $@ $<

test.tv:

$ make -f Makefile3
echo test.v test.tv
test.v test.tv
```